# Highcharts show title text overlayed on Series Pane

Tags: highcharts

I am displaying multiple panes on a single graph which uses multiple y-axes and series. The title text is being show on the right side with vertical alignment.

I want to display it overlayed on the series pane with horizontal alignment. In this pic, I have highlighted the current titles with the blue pen. *I have used the red pen to denote where I would like it to be actually*:

[image]

Here is the short version of my plot options:

```
{
  "rangeSelector": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "title": {
    "text": "Index EOD Analysis"
  },
  "tooltip": {
    "split": false,
    "shared": true
  },
  "yAxis": [
    {
      "id": "Price",
      "labels": {
        "align": "right",
        "x": -3
      },
      "title": {
        "text": "Price"
      },
      "height": "60%"
    },
    {
      "height": "20%",
      "top": "60%",
      "title": {
        "text": "Net Seller Index"
      }
    },
    {
      "height": "20%",
      "top": "80%",
      "title": {
        "text": "FII Consolidated PCR"
      }
    }
  ],
  "series": [
    {
      "name": "Price",
      "type": "candlestick",
      "yAxis": 0,
      "data": [
        [
          ...
    },
    {
      "name": "Net Seller Index",
      "type": "column",
      "yAxis": 1,
      "data": [
        ....
    },
    {
      "name": "FII Consolidated PCR",
      "type": "column",
      "yAxis": 2,
      "data": [
        ....
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Link to jsfddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/wjoqedk8/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by setting axis properties like:

```
reserveSpace: false,
textAlign: 'left',
rotation: 0,
y: 5,
style: {
   fontSize: '9px'
}
```

And to align titles to the left side of the chart plot area:

```
  chart: {
    events: {
        render: function() {
        var chart = this;

        chart.yAxis[1].axisTitle.attr({
            x: chart.plotLeft
        });

        chart.yAxis[2].axisTitle.attr({
            x: chart.plotLeft
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wqtpb21v/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.title

Comment: This seems like a good solution. But you are using absolute pre-calculated values of y in yAxis.title.y, I may be using multiple axes like 3-5 so how should I calculate the right y value? Is there a heuristic where I can use the top & height properties to calculate it dynamically?

Comment: If this answer seems like a good solution please mark it as a correct one or upvote, thanks. These values are actually "vertical pixel offset of the title position". You don't have to set them at all, I used them to make the title more readable. Without an offset, the title overlaps the series bars: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/45emszyf/